Why is the TypeScript implementation more efficient than the Rust implementation for the same functionality?
A function that takes the content of a pre-read bill file (.txt) and parses it into a specified data structure and returns it. Each line of the bill file represents a transaction (yyyy/m/d h:m - content : amount dollars. e.g., 2023/1/7 15:14 - goods1x2 goods2x2 : 24.19 dollars), and it is parsed into the following structure:
struct Item {
  content: String,
  count: String,
  price: String,
}

struct Transaction {
  date: String,
  time: String,
  status: i32,
  total_amount: String,
  account: String,
  items: Vec<Item>,
}

I implemented this functionality in both Rust and TypeScript in a Tauri project. For 1 million lines of data, the TypeScript implementation takes about 2 seconds, while the Rust implementation takes about 9 seconds.
For a small number of data lines, even if there is only one line, TypeScript is still faster than Rust.
Here is the code:
[rust code]
struct Item {
  content: String,
  count: String,
  price: String,
}

struct Transaction {
  date: String,
  time: String,
  status: i32,
  total_amount: String,
  account: String,
  items: Vec<Item>,
}

pub fn text_bill_analysis(text: String) -> tauri::ipc::Response {
  let start = std::time::Instant::now();

  let mut transactions: Vec<Transaction> = Vec::new();
  let re = Regex::new(r"(paypay|bank2|income)").unwrap();

  for line in text.lines() {
    let line = match line.find("--") {
      Some(x) => line.split_at(x).0,
      None => line,
    };
    let line = line.trim();
    if line.is_empty() {
      continue;
    }

    let parts: Vec<&str> = line.split_whitespace().collect();
    if parts.len() < 2 {
      continue;
    }

    let date_parts: Vec<&str> = parts[0].split('/').collect();
    if date_parts.len() != 3 {
      continue;
    }
    let year = date_parts[0];
    let month = format!("{:02}", date_parts[1].parse::<i32>().unwrap_or(0));
    let day = format!("{:02}", date_parts[2].parse::<i32>().unwrap_or(0));
    let date = format!("{}/{}/{}", year, month, day);

    let time_parts: Vec<&str> = parts[1].split(':').collect();
    if time_parts.len() != 2 {
      continue;
    }
    let hour = format!("{:02}", time_parts[0].parse::<i32>().unwrap_or(0));
    let minute = format!("{:02}", time_parts[1].parse::<i32>().unwrap_or(0));
    let time = format!("{}:{}", hour, minute);

    let status = if line.contains("income") {
      1
    } else if line.contains("balance") {
      2
    } else {
      0
    };

    let unit = parts.last().unwrap_or(&"");
    if *unit != "dollars" {
      continue;
    }

    let total_amount = match parts.iter().nth_back(1) {
      Some(x) => format!("{:.2}", x.parse::<f64>().unwrap_or(0.0)),
      None => continue,
    };

    let account = if line.contains("paypay") {
      "paypay"
    } else if line.contains("bank2") {
      "bank2"
    } else {
      "bank1"
    };

    let mut items: Vec<Item> = Vec::new();
    let parts_split: Vec<&str> = line.split(" - ").collect();
    if parts_split.len() < 2 {
      continue;
    }
    let parts_colon: Vec<&str> = parts_split[1].split(" : ").collect();
    if parts_colon.len() < 2 {
      continue;
    }

    let parts_filtered: Vec<&str> = parts_colon[0]
      .split_whitespace()
      .filter(|&x| !re.is_match(x))
      .collect();

    if parts_filtered.is_empty() {
      items.push(Item {
        content: "income".to_string(),
        count: "1".to_string(),
        price: "null".to_string(),
      });
    }

    let n = parts_filtered.len() as i32;
    for part in parts_filtered {
      let cleaned_part = re.replace_all(part, "").trim().to_string();
      if cleaned_part.is_empty() {
        continue;
      }

      let item_parts: Vec<&str> = cleaned_part.split('x').collect();
      let content = item_parts[0].to_string();
      let count = item_parts
        .get(1)
        .map_or(1, |x| x.parse::<i32>().unwrap_or(1))
        .to_string();

      items.push(Item {
        content,
        count,
        price: if n == 1 {
          total_amount.clone()
        } else {
          "null".to_string()
        },
      });
    }

    transactions.push(Transaction {
      date,
      time,
      status,
      total_amount,
      account: account.to_string(),
      items,
    });
  }

  let elapsed = start.elapsed();
  println!("rust: {:?}", elapsed);
  println!("len: {:?}", transactions.len());

  tauri::ipc::Response::new(serde_json::to_string(&transactions).unwrap())
}

[typescript code]
interface Item {
  content: string
  count: string
  price: string
}

interface Transaction {
  date: string
  time: string
  status: number
  totalAmount: string
  account: string
  items: Item[]
}

function textBillAnalysisTs(text: string): Transaction[] {
  console.time('ts')

  const transactions: Transaction[] = []
  const lines = text.split('\n')

  for (const _line of lines) {
    const lineWithoutComment = _line.split('--')[0]
    const line = lineWithoutComment.trim()
    if (line === '') continue

    const parts = line.split(/\s+/)
    if (parts.length < 3) continue

    const dateParts = parts[0].split('/')
    if (!dateParts || dateParts.length !== 3) continue

    const year = dateParts[0]
    const month = dateParts[1].padStart(2, '0')
    const day = dateParts[2].padStart(2, '0')
    const date = `${year}/${month}/${day}`

    const timeParts = parts[1].split(':')
    if (!timeParts || timeParts.length !== 2) continue

    const hour = timeParts[0].padStart(2, '0')
    const minute = timeParts[1].padStart(2, '0')
    const time = `${hour}:${minute}`

    const status =
      line.includes('income')
        ? 1
        : line.includes('balance')
          ? 2
          : 0

    const unit = parts[parts.length - 1]
    if (unit !== 'dollars') continue

    const totalAmount = parseFloat(parts[parts.length - 2]).toFixed(2)

    const account = line.includes('paypay')
      ? 'paypay'
      : line.includes('bank2')
        ? 'bank2'
        : 'bank1'

    const items: Item[] = []
    const partsSplit = line.split(' - ')
    const partsColon = partsSplit[1]?.split(' : ')
    if (!partsColon) continue

    const partsFiltered = partsColon[0]
      .split(/\s+/)
      .filter((x) => !['paypay', 'bank2', 'income'].includes(x))
      .map((x) => x.trim())

    if (partsFiltered.length === 0) {
      items.push({ content: 'income', count: '1', price: 'null' })
    }

    const n = partsFiltered.length
    for (const part of partsFiltered) {
      const cleanedPart = part
        .replace(/(paypay|bank2|income)/g, '')
        .trim()
      if (cleanedPart === '') continue

      const itemParts = cleanedPart.split('x')
      const content = itemParts[0] || ''
      const count = Math.max(parseInt(itemParts[1] || '1', 10), 1).toString()

      items.push({
        content,
        count,
        price: n === 1 ? totalAmount : 'null'
      })
    }

    transactions.push({
      date,
      time,
      status,
      totalAmount,
      account,
      items
    })
  }

  console.timeEnd('ts')
  return transactions
}

Below is the supported data structure:
2023/01/7 05:04 - goods1x2 goods2 : 4240.20 dollars
2023/01/07 5:4 - goods1x2 goods2 : 4240 dollars
2023/01/07 5:4 - goods1x2 goods2 : 4240.2 dollars
2023/01/07 5:4 - goods1x2 goods2 : 4240.20 dollars
2023/01/07 5:04 - goods1x2 goods2 : 4240 dollars
2023/01/07 5:04 - goods1x2 goods2 : 4240.2 dollars
2023/01/07 5:04 - goods1x2 goods2 : 4240.20 dollars
2023/01/07 05:4 - goods1x2 goods2 : 4240 dollars
2023/01/07 05:4 - goods1x2 goods2 : 4240.2 dollars
2023/01/07 05:4 - goods1x2 goods2 : 4240.20 dollars
2023/01/07 05:04 - goods1x2 goods2 : 4240 dollars
2023/01/07 05:04 - goods1x2 goods2 : 4240.2 dollars
2023/01/07 05:04 - goods1x2 goods2 : 4240.20 dollars


One thing I noticed is that your Rust code does pretty much the same stuff as the JavaScript code. It doesn't seem any attempt was made to do things in a more efficient way, such as by avoiding allocations and instead using slices when possible. If the Rust code were rewritten to actually take advantage of the ways Rust can be more efficient, the result could be different. (It's also not clear if you're testing the Rust code in release mode with optimizations, nor what benchmarking methodology was used.)

I think what's happening here is related not to the implementation of the analysis function itself and instead how Rust and TypeScript handle reading the file itself. See here: https://users.rust-lang.org/t/performance-reading-file-parse-from-io-read-vs-from-u8/91948.
If in Rust you are reading the input file like this:
let reader = BufReader::new(File::open("transactions.txt")?);
let my_thing = serde_json::from_reader(reader)?;

Then that would explain the speed difference.
In Rust, it's faster to put the whole text file into memory and read it incrementally, like:
let reader = BufReader::new(File::open("transactions.txt")?);
let mut bytes: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
reader.read_to_end(&mut bytes)?;
let my_thing = serde_json::from_slice(bytes.as_slice());

TypeScript and JavaScript perform these sorts of optimizations automatically because of the V8 engine.
I'd be curious to see if changing how the file gets read into your Rust function makes the speeds more comparable.

Thanks for your reply. In both implementations, timings do not include file reads.
